# VSS to TFS Issue

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I just moved a web app project from VSS to TFS and when I open the solution I get this message everytime.

> The solution you have opened is under source control but not currently configured for integrated source control in Visual Studio. Would you like to bind this solution to source control now?

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you click Yes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File menu/Source Control/(Advanced)/Change Source Control, then select all your project and "Unbind Them". After that you can try to bind them to TFS in the very same dialog ("Bind" command button).

Comment: This does not work when VS 2012 is only aware of VSS. The only solutions you can Bind to are those found in your VSS database. How do you remove VSS as the default source control option?

Comment: Tools/Options/Source Control/Plugin Selection switch to TFS.